# Get row index of a table javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I know this question has been asked many times, I went through most of the suggestions and none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

I have a table in a modal in which I am allowing the user to make some changes. I then use these values to update the data in the database.

My table rows are created by echoing the HTML code

```
echo "<tr> ";                   
echo "<td > $row_counter  </td>";
echo "<td style='width:200px' class='left_align' > $lstr_product_name </td>";
echo "<td  > $lstr_department_name </td>";
echo "<td  > <input type='text' name='unit_cost' class='form-control unit_cost' style='width:50px;' value='$lint_unit_cost' /> <input name='product_id' data-id='$lint_product_id' class='form-control product_id' value='$lint_product_id' type='hidden'/> </td>";
echo "<td  > $lint_quantity_counted </td>";
echo "<td  > $lint_total_cost </td>";
```

To update the proper values in the database I need to get the product_id name which I know that I can get by

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("product_id")[0].value;
```

However I need to get the correct row index to be able to POST the correct product_id.

I have tried the following:

```
alert($(this).index());
```

But this always returns 0. The closest I got to a solution was by using

```
var rowID = $(this).closest('tr').index();
alert(rowID);
```

The problem with this is that my editable cell is "unit_cost" which is the 4th cell in the tr. This means that the closest tr is not the one that the row that the cell is in but the one below.

I have then tried

```
alert( "Row id: " + $("#tbl_store_product_sizes tr").this.rowIndex );
```

But also no luck. I have ran out of ideas, what is the proper way of doing this?

**EDIT**
All my javascript code is enclosed in the $(document).ready(function() 
I am watching for the change of the unit_cost field using the following code

```
$(document.body).off( "change", ".unit_cost");
$(document.body).on('change', '.unit_cost', function(event) 
{

    var rowID = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    alert(rowID);
    var product_id = document.getElementsByName("product_id")[rowID].value;
    alert('The product id is: ' + x);
    var unit_cost = document.getElementsByName("unit_cost")[rowID].value;


});
```

Comment: try to add a class to your `tr`, for example 'row', and call : `var rowID = $(this).closest('tr.row').index();`

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question, but how this is going to help? Would it still not look for the closest tr with class row, which still would be the one below the actual row? I just don't get the logic behind it, can you explain more?

Comment: If i understand what you are trying to say, you need next(), not closest(): $(this).parent().next('tr').index()?

Comment: Not really, you see closest(); seems to be getting the next row index, rather than the current one. So if I edit the first row, I am expecting to get rowID = 0, but I get rowID = 1. Unless closest() uses different index on the returned values?

Comment: No, closest() doesn't return next row index at all. Please provide complete HTML generated by php.

Comment: @sinisake I know closest() doesn't return the next row index, I figured it should return the one that is closest to the element that I am editing, in which case it's the row below. Complete html for the table can be seen here https://pastebin.com/sivJtTMh

Comment: @artlemaks  you need to change your script code like below(Given in my answer). Also `input type="text" and  type="hidden"` on the same input will not work. You have to use either-one

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, and that caused problems, check your form tags... https://jsfiddle.net/dzmuuxyu/1/

Comment: Always something simple... That works even better than the other answer, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Explanation:-***

Since both inputs are in the same `<td>`, so on change of first-one you have to use `.next()` to get next input data.

***You need to do it like below:-***

```
$(document).on('change', '.unit_cost', function(event) {

    var rowID = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    alert(rowID);
    var product_id = $(this).next('.product_id').val();
    alert('The product id is: ' + product_id);
    var unit_cost = $(this).val();
});
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).on('change', '.unit_cost', function(event) {

    var rowID = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    alert('The corresponding row index is: '+ rowID);
    var product_id = $(this).next('.product_id').val();
    alert('The product id is: ' + product_id);
    var unit_cost = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td style='width:200px' class='left_align'>2 </td>
  <td>3 </td>
  <td> <input type='text' name='unit_cost' class='form-control unit_cost' style='width:50px;' value='4' /> <input name='product_id' data-id='$lint_product_id' class='form-control product_id' value='5' type="hidden"/> </td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>8</td>
  <td style='width:200px' class='left_align'>9 </td>
  <td>10 </td>
  <td> <input type='text' name='unit_cost' class='form-control unit_cost' style='width:50px;' value='11' /><input name='product_id' data-id='$lint_product_id' class='form-control product_id' value='12' type="hidden"/> </td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
</tr>
</table>
```